# Eclipse error during remote debug session: sh: locale: not found

Tags: c++, linux, eclipse, locale, remote-debugging

I'm really hoping to get an answer on this. I am using Eclipse to remote debug a C++ program on a (minimal) linux machine. I am aware that the linux machine does not have the locale binary installed. First off, the error received is the following in Eclipse after pressing the debug or run button:

> org.eclipse.remote.core.exception.RemoteConnectionException: sh:
>   locale: not found

After the first run, successive runs do not display the error, only the first run. If I restart the linux machine, the error will come back for the first run again.

What is most obvious is that Eclipse, or the running program is calling locale on the linux machine and it is not available, not installed.

This machine is quite minimal and doesn't even have a package manager - it's an embedded system. So I tried to install "locales", "locale" as well as "locale-all" using multistrap when building the linux image. None worked.
When using debian repositories, multistrap returns

> E: Unable to locate packages locales

So I guess my real questions are:

> 1) What debian package supplies "locale" found in /usr/bin/locale? How
>   can I install it without adding a lot of of overhead on an ARM system? (assuming no package manager)
>
> 2) Where is the source code for locale?

And third,

> 3) In Eclipse, can I prevent the running program or Eclipse from
>   calling locale? This is preferred.

After scouring the forums, I found one guy that said he got the same issue and "manually fixed it", however he did not provide the fix.. Hope to get some help!
That reference can be found https://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/t/1081283/

Thanks,

Answer (score 4):

I had the same, so I changed the encoding to ISO-8859-1 in the debug settings.

Comment: No longer on that project! Maybe this solution will help the next guy!

Comment: yes. I see it is too late. Someone may need it.
That's why I posted this.